# What does the safe navigation operator look like for closures in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Consider the following example:

```
def c = { println it }
c("hello, world!")
```

This script should execute without error. But what if c were never defined (ie null)?

```
def c = null
c("hello, world!")
```

This script would have a runtime error. Is there a safe navigation operator for use in this case or am I stuck with the if condition?

```
def c = { println it }
c?.("hello, world!")
```

This script doesn't appear to work when c is not null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the longer [`call()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#call%28%29) form, ie:

```
c?.call( 'hello world?' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you could just use a no-op closure instead of null.

```
final c = { println it }
c('hello world')
```

```
final c = {}
c('hello world')
```